# Do you release the object which is being returned in a function?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

This is for an iPhone APP written in Objective-C using Xcode 4.

The quick question is if you have a function which returns an NSArray which was ALLOC'ed in that function, do you have to release it?

Here is the more detailed question.

I run "Analyse" on my iPhone app and it complains about a possible memory leak on one of my functions

The function creates a NSArray out of a NSMutableArray and returns the NSArray.  What I am doing is taking an NSMutableArray of class objects and creating an NSArray of NSStrings out of them.  I have simplified the code as much as possible to show the problem so don't worry if it looks like its not doing anything useful.

```
-(NSArray *)encodeArray
{
    // I use a NSMutableArray here because I do not know how big the starting
    // array will be (I hard coded the 20 here for now)
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

    for (int y = 0;y<20;y++) {
        // create the NSString object and add it to the tmp array
        NSString *cardcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%",y];
        [tmp addObject:cardcount];
    }
    // create the array we will be returning out of the NSMutableArray
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmp copyItems:YES];
    // release the tmp array we created.
    [tmp release];

    // return our array
    // This is the location of the potential memory leak.  SHOULD I RELEASE THIS
    // If I DO - HOW DO I RETURN IT.
    return array;
}
```

Do I need to release the array?  If so, how can I still return it?   Maybe there is a better way to perform what I am doing?

The overall goal is to create a NSArray so that I can use the NSUserDefaults to save the application state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb; if you (by *you* I mean the current scope of the object) retain/copy/etc an object, then you must release/autorelease it somewhere.  Since whoever calls `encodeArray` didn't do the retaining on `array`, they are not responsible for releasing it.  Therefore, it needs to be set to be autoreleased before being returned:

```
-(NSArray *)encodeArray
{
    // I use a NSMutableArray here because I do not know how big the starting
    // array will be (I hard coded the 20 here for now)
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int y = 0;y<20;y++) {
        // create the NSString object and add it to the tmp array
        NSString *cardcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%",y];
        [tmp addObject:cardcount];
    }

    // create the array we will be returning out of the NSMutableArray
    // Named initializers indicate that the object will be autoreleased:
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tmp];

    // release the tmp array we created.
    [tmp release];

    // return our array
    return array;
}
```

Or:

```
-(NSArray *)encodeArray
{
    // I use a NSMutableArray here because I do not know how big the starting
    // array will be (I hard coded the 20 here for now)
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int y = 0;y<20;y++) {
        // create the NSString object and add it to the tmp array
        NSString *cardcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%",y];
        [tmp addObject:cardcount];
    }
    // create the array we will be returning out of the NSMutableArray
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tmp];

    // release the tmp array we created.
    [tmp release];

    // return our array
    return [array autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation and the sample code backing it up.  Not only did it fix my problem, but I learned something as well.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you want to return an auto-released array in this case. IF you release it in your function, it will be deallocated before your caller has a chance to retain its own copy. If you don't autorelease it, then when your caller retains the returned object you will have a retain count of 2, and it is likely to leak.

So, just change your return statement to this:

```
return [array autorelease];
```